# How to get least number of occurrence of data in other database table?

Tags: mysql, sql

**I want to get the Agent who has the least number of orders in table B.**

also include Agent D. suppose as in the below table Agent D not having any order so in this case Required Answer is Agent D and if Agent D is also in Table B then I want Agent Who to have the least order.

[image: Database Table Example]

if any more explanation is needed then please comment on the question I am ready to reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: What have you tried till now?

Comment: currently, I am using PHP. by taking Agent A and check num_rows and same with all Agent and then pick the smallest one (num_rows). but I want a query for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by summarising the order tableB in terms of the number of orders per agent:

```
SELECT Agent, count(agent) as orders FROM TableB group by agent;
```

Then JOIN this back to agents in TableA with a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT A.Agent, ifnull(B.orders,0) AS ORDERS 
FROM TableA as A 
  LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT Agent, count(agent) as orders 
     FROM TableB 
      GROUP BY agent
    ) AS B 
  ON (A.Agent = B.agent)
ORDER BY orders DESC;
```

This will return a list of all the agents along with their order totals from Table B, but any agents who have no orders will appear in this result with NULL orders. Use IFNULL() to place a zero in those values, and order by order total descending.

Output:

| Agent | orders |
| --- | --- |
| B | 4 |
| C | 3 |
| A | 2 |
| D | 0 |

Comment: Thank you so much !!
It's the same as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method or this code to check
SELECT name,COUNT(*)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;

Comment: This will only return those agents who have orders. Agent D has no orders so won't appear.